# How to find delta in pandas data-frame rows with specific conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I need to compute delta column (as shown below). But tricky part is conditions mentioned below. How can I do this in pandas?

```
speaker | video | frame | time |delta(expected)
--------|-------|-------|------|----------------
one     |1      | 0     |10    |0
one     |1      | 1     |15    |5
one     |2      | 0     |12    |0
one     |2      | 1     |16    |4
two     |2      | 0     |19    |0
two     |2      | 1     |22    |3
two     |2      | 2     |16    |-6
```

**CONDITIONS:**
Delta is a difference between frames of same speaker with same video.  In other words, delta should not be computed on rows for different speakers or different videos. For those cases the value should be initialized as zero as showed in delta(expected) column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let't use `groupby`, `diff`, and `fillna`:

```
df['delta'] = df.groupby(['speaker','video'])['time'].diff().fillna(0)
```

Output:

```
    speaker  video  frame  time  delta(expected)  delta
0  one           1      0    10                0    0.0
1  one           1      1    15                5    5.0
2  one           2      0    12                0    0.0
3  one           2      1    16                4    4.0
4  two           2      0    19                0    0.0
5  two           2      1    22                3    3.0
6  two           2      2    16               -6   -6.0
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 3):

**Option 1**
Assuming `df` is sorted by `['speaker', 'video']`.  If not, then do so.

```
delta = np.where(
    df.duplicated(['speaker', 'video']).values,
    np.append(0, np.diff(df.time.values)), 0
)

df.assign(delta=delta)

  speaker  video  frame  time  delta(expected)  delta
0     one      1      0    10                0      0
1     one      1      1    15                5      5
2     one      2      0    12                0      0
3     one      2      1    16                4      4
4     two      2      0    19                0      0
5     two      2      1    22                3      3
6     two      2      2    16               -6     -6
```

---

**Option 2**

```
df.assign(
    delta=df.groupby(['speaker', 'video']).time.transform(
        lambda x: np.append(0, np.diff(x.values))
    )
)

  speaker  video  frame  time  delta(expected)  delta
0     one      1      0    10                0      0
1     one      1      1    15                5      5
2     one      2      0    12                0      0
3     one      2      1    16                4      4
4     two      2      0    19                0      0
5     two      2      1    22                3      3
6     two      2      2    16               -6     -6
```

Comment: piRSquared - Thanks for your help and mentioning sorted option.